# Problem of creating several VMs with different names by using the concat of names and copyindex in variable of an ARM code

Tags: azure, copy, virtual-machine

I am looking to create an ARM template code to be able to deploy several VMs with different names using copy and copyindex. To achieve this, I turned to this Microsoft procedure:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "storageNames": {
          "type": "array",
          "defaultValue": [
            "contoso",
            "fabrikam",
            "coho"
          ]
      }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('storageNames')[copyIndex()], uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {},
      "copy": {
        "name": "storagecopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('storageNames'))]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

But I have problem when I use array with concat and variables too. it gives me several errors. Can you help me make this code? I would like to use the minimum parameter.

here are my 2 different templates:

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VMNames": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "vmSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_B2s"
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
        "VnetName": "[concat(resourceGroup().name, '-vnet1')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-pip01')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
            },
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "domainNameLabel": "[toLower(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name)]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nsg01')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "nsgRule1",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "description",
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('VnetName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nsg01')]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[ concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-subnet')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nsg01')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nic01')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/',  concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-pip01'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('VnetName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipConfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',  concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-pip01'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[resourceId( 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',variables('VnetName'),  concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-subnet'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "vmcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]",
                "mode": "Serial"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/',  concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nic01'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].size]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name]",
                    "adminUsername": "cprin",
                    "adminPassword": "Vivendi$1234"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[ concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-OsDisk01')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',  concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nic01'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

the 2nd different:

```
   {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VMNames": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "vmSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_B2s"
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
        "NSGName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-nsg01')]",
        "NicName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-nic01')]",
        "VnetName": "[concat(resourceGroup().name[copyIndex()], '-vnet1')]",
        "publicNicName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-pip01')]",
        "OsDiskName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-OsDisk01')]",
        "subnetName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-subnet')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[variables('publicNicName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
            },
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "domainNameLabel": "[toLower(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()])]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('NSGName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "nsgRule1",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "description",
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('VnetName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', variables('NSGName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('NSGName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('NicName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicNicName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('VnetName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipConfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicNicName'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[resourceId( 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',variables('VnetName'), variables('subnetName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "vmcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]",
                "mode": "Serial"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('NicName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]",
                    "adminUsername": "cprin",
                    "adminPassword": "Vivendi$1234"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[variables('OsDiskName')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('NicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

and here is my parameter file for my 1st code:

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VMNames": {
            "value": [
                {
                "name": "vmfakri",
                "size": "Standard_B2s"
                },
                {
                "name": "vmrazane",
                "size": "Standard_B2s"
                },
                {
                "name": "vmseif",
                "size": "Standard_B2s"
                }
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my parameter file for my 2nd code:

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VMNames": {
            "value": [
                "vmfakri",
                "vmrazane",
                "vmseif"
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

Here are the errors encountered:

```
InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'NSGName' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy
```

specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.

```
InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[concat(parameters('VMNames'), '-pip01')]' at line '24' and column '9' is not valid: The provided parameters for language function 'concat' are
```

invalid. Either all or none of the parameters must be an array. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#concat for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you might be missing iteration property in resource deployment:
add "copy" property.

```
 {
    "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()].name, '-nsg01')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
    "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
    "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
            {
                "name": "nsgRule1",
                "properties": {
                    "description": "description",
                    "protocol": "Tcp",
                    "sourcePortRange": "*",
                    "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                    "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                    "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                    "access": "Allow",
                    "priority": 100,
                    "direction": "Inbound"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "copy": {
        "name": "VMcopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]"
    }
}
```

In this case you don't need to iterate in variable

**Edited**

Here is updated ARM template that was successfully validated.
I removed iteration over most of your variables and added iteration over resource.

I noticed that you wanted to have one VNET with multiple subnets so also added iteration over only "subnet" property
I believe you may modify it further to fit your needs.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VMNames": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "vmSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_B2s"
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "NSGName",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex('NSGName')], '-nsg01')]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-pip01')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
            },
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "domainNameLabel": "[toLower(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()])]"
                }
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "VMcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-nsg01')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "nsgRule1",
                        "properties": {
                            "description": "description",
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 100,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "VMcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(resourceGroup().name, '-vnet1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "subnets",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "subnets": [
                                {
                                    "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex('subnets')], '-subnet')]",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "addressPrefix": "[concat('10.0.',copyIndex('subnets'), '.0/24')]",
                                        "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex('subnets')], '-nsg01'))]"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-nic01')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-pip01'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', concat(resourceGroup().name, '-vnet1'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipConfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-pip01'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[resourceId( 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',concat(resourceGroup().name, '-vnet1'), concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-subnet'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "VMcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "VMcopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-nic01'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()]]",
                    "adminUsername": "cprin",
                    "adminPassword": "Vivendi$1234"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-OsDisk01')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-nic01'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

and parameter file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VMNames": {
            "value": [
                "vmfakri",
                "vmrazane",
                "vmseif"
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Greg, I just did what you told me but there is still an error:

InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'NSGName' is not valid: The provided parameters for language function 'concat' are invalid. Either all or
none of the parameters must be an array. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#concat for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage
details.'.